# Create An Contact Shortcut for Hangouts

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, samsung-galaxy-tab, google-hangouts

How can I create a Hangouts contact shortcut for video calling on the desktop for Samsung Galaxy Tab A ( Android 5.0.1) ? I searched it a lot of. But, I cannot find any solution ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I don't have that app currently but want to clarify something: do you want to create a shortcut for a particular contact or a shortcut which would show the list of contacts for video calling?

Comment: When I clicked to shortcut, it will do a video chat with "X" person who is in my Hangouts contacts.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do something like that.

You have 2 options:

1. Create a widget that the Hangouts app provides for that
2. Use a custom launcher, to make a custom shortcut to the specific function/activity

Since the app doesn't provide such a widget and the 2nd option can at best open your contact list from a shortcut (tested it), there is unfortunately no other option to get something like that.